# Fat Query fragment not included in the query sent to GraphQL

Tags: relayjs

The mutation query that is being sent to GraphQL does not include the result of the intersection between the track query and my Fat Query.

This is my Mutation class:

```js
getMutation() {
  return Relay.QL`mutation { updateTag }`
}

getVariables() {
  return {
    id: this.props.id,
    name: this.props.name,
    isFollowed: this.props.isFollowed,
  }
}

getFatQuery() {
  return Relay.QL`
    fragment on UpdateTagPayload {
      viewer {
        followedTags {
          tagList {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `;
}

getConfigs() {
  return [
    {
      type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
      fieldIDs: {
        viewer: this.props.viewerID,
      },
    },
  ]
}
```

And this is the resulting query, sent to GraphQL:

```
mutation FollowTagMutation($input_0:UpdateTagInput!) {
  updateTag(input:$input_0) {
    clientMutationId
  }
}
```

I would expect part of the fields defined in my Fat Query to also be there.

In the console, the **Tracked Fragment Variables** is an empty object (`Object{}`), and the **Tracked Fragment Query** is just empty.

So it seems like, when the track and the fat query are intercepted, the result is an empty Intersection Query.

Any help on* this? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution to my issue is two-folded:

1. Use `this.props.relay.commitUpdate`, instead of `Relay.Store.commitUpdate`:

   At this point, I don't really know why (can't find docs about this), but using the latter just didn't work in my case. Once I find out, I'll update this point.
2. Connect the `viewer` in my Fat Query to the `viewer` in the my local Relay store.

   This is related to the suggestions provided by the other answers here (thanks @maplechori and @Ahmad Ferdous!).

   However, it's not necessary to create the `static fragments` bit in the Mutation class; I just make sure to fetch `viewer { id }` via Relay in the React component, and pass it to the Mutation via `props`, so it's used in the `getConfigs()` bit.

Comment: Could you post the code that worked?

I don't really understand what you mean by `Connect the viewer in my Fat Query to the viewer in the my local Relay store`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to set the fragment on the FollowTagMutation and then pull it with ${FollowTagMutation.getFragment('viewer')} on the component calling that mutation.

Then make sure to pass the viewer on Relay.Store.commitUpdate(new FollowTagMutation( viewer: this.props.viewer ..... on that same component.

Comment: OK, so I set up the React component that calls the `FollowTagMutation` to include the `${FollowTagMutation.getFragment('viewer')}` on the Relay.QL part. 
And I do `Relay.Store.commitUpdate(new FollowTagMutation({ ..., viewer: this.props.viewer}));`
But on the mutation class, in `getConfigs()`, `this.props.viewer` is coming `undefined`.

Comment: Also, I'm getting this error on the console when I trigger the mutation: **RelayMutation: Expected prop `viewer` supplied to `FollowTagMutation` to be data fetched by Relay.**

Answer (score 0):

(This is suitable for a comment. I'm putting it here to maintain code formatting.)

Based on your information, I suspect you need to make viewer ID available to get the intended result. Add `fragments` to `FollowTagMutation` mutation:

```
  static fragments = {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer {
        id,
      }
    `,
  };
```

Comment: This seems to be related to @maplechori's answer. Thanks!